# How to add a custom part to a spring-data Repository method name?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, repository

I have a repository and want to add two methods that perform "the same" operation (e.g. find by id), but one method eagerly fetches some data. Is it possible to add a custom part to the name to allow for both methods to exist and to inform the caller about what the methods do?

For example:

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository {

    Optional<User> findById(UUID id);
    
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"posts", "comments"})
    Optional<User> findByIdEagerlyFetchingPostsAndComments(UUID id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place method marker (`EagerlyFetchingPostsAndComments` in your case) between `(find|read|get|query|search|stream)` and `By`, for example:

```java
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"posts", "comments"})
Optional<User> findEagerlyFetchingPostsAndCommentsById(UUID id);
```